# Input/Output with kanji/hiragana (Japanese) in JAVA?

Tags: java, utf-8, compilation

I recently made a language program which runs pretty fine. There is only one problem. Once exported the program writes all non-latin characters as a combination of 'ã's math-signs and other various characters. How do I solve this?

I need to be able to write with foreign characters (in this case Japanese characters) and for the program to be able to write with foreign characters in my GUI. The program also needs to be able to write and read text files with these characters.

The program runs fine in Eclipse but once I export it and run it elsewhere it is another story.

Help is appreciated.